# SQL: select rows from a certain table based on conditions in this and another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that share IDs on a postgresql . 
I would like to select certain rows from table A, based on condition Y (in table A) AND based on Condition Z in a different table (B) ).
For example:

```
Table A                  Table B
ID  |  type             ID  |  date
0      E                1      01.01.2022
1      F                2      01.01.2022 
2      E                3      01.01.2010
3      F
```

IDs MUST by unique - the same ID can appear only once in each table, and if the same ID is in both tables it means that both are referring to the same object.
Using an SQL query, I would like to find all cases where:
1 - the same ID exists in both tables
2 - type is F
3 - date is after 31.12.2021
And again, only rows from table A will be returned.
So the only returned row should be:`1    F`

Comment: 1) What if a row in A is not present in B? 2) What if a row in A has multiple matches in B?

Comment: sorry just updated: IDs must be unique.
Regarding Question 1: I don't care about such row. I just need the cases where both conditions match for the same ID. But tbh I think that the same IDs should be always both tables...

Comment: What does "must be unique" mean? Is it guaranteed that the ID is unique in table A? Is it guaranteed that the ID is unique in table B?

Comment: I clarified it further. Thanks.  The same ID can appear only once in each table, and if the same ID is in both tables it means that both are referring to the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
WHERE type='F'
AND id IN (
SELECT id 
FROM B
WHERE DATE>='2022-01-01'; -- '2022' imo should be enough, need to check
);
```

I don't think joining is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hard t understand what problem you are actually facing, as this is very basic SQL.

Use `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from a
where type = 'F'
and exists (select null from b where b.id = a.id and dt >= date '2022-01-01');
```

Or `IN`:

```
select *
from a
where type = 'F'
and id in (select id from b where dt >= date '2022-01-01');
```

Or, as the IDs are unique in both tables, join:

```
select a.*
from a
join b on b.id = a.id
where a.type = 'F'
and b.dt >= date '2022-01-01';
```

My favorite here is the `IN` clause, because you want to select data from table A where conditions are met. So no join needed, just a where clause, and `IN` is easier to read than `EXISTS`.